# Animate content out with iron router in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I would like to make an animation to my content before the router change template. So far I have this:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  TweenMax.to("section", 1, { opacity: 0 });
  var thisAction = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    thisAction.next(); // Returns this:  Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
  }, 1000);

});
```

Can anybody tell me the best way to do this? :)

Cheers

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution, so for people who google this:

The name is _uihooks. Events placed on the DOM element.

Examples can be seen here: 
http://www.webtempest.com/meteorjs-animation

Can't find any other documentation than this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/30fb11f1fa0227f1c0ec3eb30b7864ea3b2d210e/History.md#blaze-1

Cheers

Peter